# Sequence Container

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssis, containers, sequence

Hi I am using Sequence container in SSIS,

i have 3 tasks in a sequence container, first task is executing fine, second one is failing, so third one is not executing, though the second one is failing i want third to be executed weather is  it success or failure, when the second one is getting failed, it is not allowing third one to execute, my question is any task is failed in the sequence container, it should execute all the tasks in the Container.

Comment: Just simple sentences is not enough to help your problem.Please post some codes what you have tried or which will explain your problem clearly

Answer (score 0):

Click on the task and then in the properties windows, set `FailParentOnFailure` to `False` (I think this is the default).

Next, click the connector between this task and the following task and change the `Value` property from `Success` to `Completion`